# Bufferization in GzipFile

Tags: python, buffer, gzip, buffering

Imagine the following simple script:

```
def reader():
    for line in open('logfile.log'):
        # do some stuff here like splitting the line or filtering etc.
        yield some_new_line

def writer(stream):
    with gzip.GzipFile('some_output_file.gz', 'w') as fh:
        for _s in stream:
            fh.write(_s+'\n')

stream = reader()
writer(stream)
```

So pretty simple - read lines using generators and write some result into a gzip file.

But how to speed it up? The HDD seems to be a bottleneck. I saw I can use buffer size for reads - using *open(file, mode, buffer)* syntax. But I'm not quite sure it will work in my case (with generators).

Also I didn't find any bufferization parameter for the gzip.GzipFile call. From the code, it's based on some bufferized class, but I don't see any further docs on that.

I have a (crazy?) idea to create an explicit cache and replace open methods with it - so it will read the file in bigger chunks, say, by 8MB, and then perform splitting it by lines. As for writes, I thought to create a list of lines to write, collect them (say, 5000 lines), and then dump into the file.

Am I trying to re-invent the wheel? I'm not satisfied with the performance the script currently has, so I'm trying to speed it up as much as possible.

UPD. I have around 4-5 different parallel workers running. They all perform reads and writes. So I guess the HDD is jumping from one sector to another, and this is the reason why I want to implement some bufferization to dump the data periodically in big chunks.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a crazy idea. But python already does the cache job while iterating the file so you may only need to optimize the write part.

Answer (score 0):

I can just propose more compact code:

```
def reader():
    for line in open('logfile.log'):
        # do some stuff here like splitting the line or filtering etc.
        yield some_new_line

def writer(stream):
    with gzip.GzipFile('some_output_file.gz', 'w') as fh:
        fh.writelines(stream)

writer(reader())
```

However, there is no actual speed-up. Python will manage the streams, but if you cannot spare memory for full file write, the speed-up will not be great.

The compression though gzip is the slowest step. The following function will give you only ~3% speed-up (disregarding the generator's part).

```
def writer():
   f = open('logfile.log').read()
   gzip.GzipFile('some_output_file.gz', 'w').write(f)
writer()
```

So, if you need gzip, than you cannot do much.

Comment: do you mean, the gzip algorithm itself is slow and it takes too much CPU time? I have around 4-5 different parallel processes, they perform reads and writes and the HDD spends a lot of time jumping from one sector to another. That's why I'd like to buffer the data, and dump it to the HDD from time to time

Comment: @Spaceman: The gzip.write takes more than 90% of the time for execution of your code. If you substitute your writer with a plain save: "with open('some_output_file', 'w') as fh:  fh.writelines(stream)", then your code executes for miliseconds for a small input file. If you use gzip in the writer, then it takes seconds for the same input file. My conclusion is that gzip, slows down the code with a factor of at least 100.